# ActiveRecord/Devise not providing a 'has already been taken error'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a model, with some customised devise keys, like so:

```
:authentication_keys => [:username],
:reset_password_keys => [:username],
:strip_whitespace_keys => [:username]
```

I have also overriden the following method so that Devise doesn't expect a unique email address:

```
def will_save_change_to_email?
  false
end
```

The problem is that I'm not receiving an ActiveRecord `'has already been taken'` error until all other expectations are met, at which point I receive `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` as expected.

Can anybody please help?

Thank you.

Edit: adding `uniqueness: true` ensures the error message is returned instantly, but I suspect I shouldn't have to add this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I realised that when editing the authentication key for Devise, you *do* have to specify this on the model.

Seeing as the field already existed on my model, I skimmed over the below line from the [Devise Guide](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Allow-users-to-sign-in-with-something-other-than-their-email-address) and missed the `:uniq` at the very end.

```
rails generate migration add_username_to_users username:string:uniq
```